# LINQ Query Problem

Tags: linq

I want to use this in my application but I'm getting an error for

```
GetByLatest().Cast<IRss>();
```

I am getting an error to this line GetByLatest(),please tell how shall I implement this one

Please suggest a solution

```
IList<IRss> news = new Trytable().GetByLatest().Cast<IRss>();
return new RssResult(news, "William Duffy - Glasgow Based ASP.NET Web Developer",
        "The latest news on ASP.NET, C# and ASP.NET MVC ");
```

Comment: Can you please add the error message?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490408/getbylatest

Answer (score 1):

The result of `Cast` will be `IEnumerable<IRss>` - not `IList<IRss>`. If you want to use an `IList<IRss>` variable you need to call `ToList` (or `ToArray`):

```
IList<IRss> news = new Trytable().GetByLatest().Cast<IRss>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

A Google search for William Duffy indicates that you were trying to use [this code](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/rssresult-aspnet-mvc-rss-actionresult/):

```
        IEnumerable<IRss> news = new NewsService().GetByLatest().Cast<IRss>();
        return new RssResult(news, "William Duffy - Glasgow Based ASP.NET Web Developer", "The latest news on ASP.NET, C# and ASP.NET MVC ");
```

Can you explain what you're trying to do so we can actually help?