# GetByLatest in LINQ?

Tags: linq

Please provide me a solution for GetByLatest it is giving me an error

How to use this "GetByLatest"

```
IList<IRss> news = new Trytable().GetByLatest().Cast<IRss>().ToList();
```

i used this way in the controller,still it is giving an error for getbylatest in the feed method

public static IEnumerable GetByLatest(this IEnumerable unsorted)
        {
            return from item in unsorted
                   orderby item.Link descending
                   select item;
        }
        public ActionResult Feed()
        {

```
        IEnumerable<IRss> news = new IEnumerable<IRss>.GetByLatest().Cast<IRss>().ToList();

            //IList<IRss> news = new Trytable().GetByLatest().Cast<IRss>();
            //return new RssResult(news, "William Duffy - Glasgow Based ASP.NET Web Developer", "The latest news on ASP.NET, C# and ASP.NET MVC ");

    }
```

please help me

Thanks
Ritz

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490341/query-problem-please-help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the publication date for an individual RSS item is in the property `PubDate` and `Trytable()` returns an `IEnumerable<IRss>`, `GetByLatest` would look something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IRss> GetByLatest(this IEnumerable<IRss> unsorted)
{
    return from item in unsorted
           orderby item.PubDate descending
           select item;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be `IEnumerable<IRss>`, not `IList<IRss>`. Or, better yet, use `var`.

Comment: What would the point of calling ".ToList()" to then cast it down to IEnumerable<T>?